# How parse nested json in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have nested JSON with bunch of children objects, but I just need response_time and question, subquestions of survey_data. What is the best way to parse nested JSON in rest controller to the object in spring?

```
{
   "is_test_data":false,
   "language":"English",
   "url_variables":{
      "requestId":{
         "key":"requestId",
         "value":"1"
      }
   },
   "response_time":1114,
   "survey_data":{
      "2":{
         "id":2,
         "type":"parent",
         "question":"For each of the following factors, please rate your recent project",
         "subquestions":{
            "10":{
               "10001":{
                  "id":10001,
                  "type":"MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                  "question":"Overall Quality : Rating",
                  "answer":null,
               }
            }, 
            "11":{
               "10001":{
                  "id":10001,
                  "type":"MULTI_TEXTBOX",               
                  "question":"Achievement of Intended Objectives : Rating",
                  "answer":null
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "33":{
         "id":33,
         "type":"HIDDEN",
         "question":"Submitted",
         "answer_id":0,
      }
   }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: parse the whole JSON end then get only the informations you need?...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia  I'm trying to use Jackson annotations. For start I created class ResponseDTO with 2 fields: responseTime and language. I used @JsonProperty()  for them. Rest method signature is:    
 ```@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity addAnswer (@RequestBody final ResponseDTO dto, final HttpServletRequest request) 
```
What am I missing? or it is not a right approach?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is parse the complete json to jsonObject using json-simple jar
which create a map like structure for the json and then you can simply get the desired value from it using the key as I explained in below example

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class JsonDeserializer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("test.json");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())))) {
        int c = 0;
        while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
            textBuilder.append((char) c);
        }
    }
    String jsonTxt = textBuilder.toString();
    Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(jsonTxt);
    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;

    System.out.println(jo.get("response_time"));

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a data communication format that is lightweight, text-based. Objects and arrays are two structured kinds that JSON can represent. A JSONArray may extract text from a String and convert it to a vector-like object. The getString(index) method of JSONArray can be used to parse a nested JSON object. This is a helper method for the getJSONString method (index). The getString() method returns a string.